# Binding to local variable in codebehind

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8

I have to bind to local variable from code behind in ListView.ItemTemplate. I have tried using datacontext:

```
            <ListView Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MaxHeight="300" Background="White" Foreground="Black" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="#FFCDCDCD" BorderThickness="1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IncrementalLoadingTrigger="None" SelectionChanged="listView_SelectionChanged" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxHeight="25" >
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Text}" Width="{Binding Width}" />
                            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="None" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

In place of "Width="{Binding Width}"" I want to have property from datacontext - rest of data is connected with itemsSource. How to "tell" xaml to use property from datacontext? (right now it returns error "property not found"). I don't want to change my itemsource and add there width because it is constant for every element (it's obvious ;) ).

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *does* use the `DataContext`, which for the `ItemTemplate` is the item. You can walk up the tree to find another `DataContext`, in this case you want the `ListView's`:

```
{Binding DataContext.Width,
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}
```

Comment: On window 8 there is no ancestor type but i used elementName=listView. Thanks :)